# kafka not retreiving data from clickhouse

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, clickhouse

I have to push data from Clickhouse to Kafka topics,so I tried to use the Confluent JDBC connector.
i am following [this](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) tutorial that uses mysql instead of clickhouse.
here is my configuration and its works with mysql but has this error with clickhouse.

```
Missing columns: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' while processing query: 'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', required columns: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', source columns: 'dummy' (version 19.17.4.11 (official build))
```

my configuration:

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_source_clickhouse_my-table_01",
    "config": {
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",

            "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

            "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",

            "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",


            "connection.url": "jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123/default?user=default&password=12344esz",

            "table.whitelist": "my-table",

            "mode": "timestamp",

            "timestamp.column.name": "order_time",

            "validate.non.null": "false",

            "topic.prefix": "clickhouse-"
    }
```

}

Comment: Please show the schema of your table. Have you tried changing the `mode` property?